# How to override bitbake file conflicts

Tags: yocto, rpm, bitbake

Working on a couple of recipe's that have file conflicts with base packages.I am trying to figure out how to force override the conflicts. In particular I am overwriting the /etc/network/interfaces file with a custom one within my recipe. How do I tell bitbake that the file(s) in my package are to take precedence over the file(s) from the base packages?

I am using RPM as the package management subsystem with in the build environment.

```
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /etc/network/interfaces conflicts between attempted installs of router-1.0-r0.noarch and init-ifupdown-1.0-r7.qemuarm64
  file /etc/udhcpc.d/50default conflicts between attempted installs of router-1.0-r0.noarch and busybox-udhcpc-1.24.1-r0.aarch64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Either don't install one of the packages in the conflict or override the original recipe's file with a bbappend.

Comment: Ill give that a try. Thanks.